# having problems setting ".$_SESSION['Username']."

Tags: php, session

My script worked when I just set the username manual to Admin, but now i need to set the username to ".$_SESSION['Username'].", and thats make some trouble for my code.

I have tried setting it in different ways, and now i cant figure out if there is more problems or if its just the username that isnt working.

My code goes:

```
    <?php
 include "connect.php";
 include "head.php";
 ?>

<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];
if($action == "fight"){
$checkfight = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fights WHERE User=".$_SESSION['Username']."")); //Check if fight exist
$monstername = $checkfight['monstername'];
$monsterlevel = $checkfight['monsterlevel'];
$monsterdice = $checkfight['monsterdice'];
$monsterhp = $checkfight['monsterhp'];
$monstermana = $checkfight['monstermana'];
$monsterarmor = $checkfight['monsterarmor'];
$monstermindmg = $checkfight['monstermindmg'];
$monstermaxdmg = $checkfight['monstermaxdmg'];

if($checkfight['User'] == 'Admin') {

$selectuser = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username=".$_SESSION['Username']."")); //loading the user
$currently = $selectuser['Quest'];
$userhp = $selectuser['Life'];
$usermana = $selectuser['Mana'];
$usermindmg = $selectuser['mindmg'];
$usermaxdmg = $selectuser['maxdmg'];
$userdice = $selectuser['dice'];

$fightMonster = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("UPDATE fights SET Player1hp='$userhp', Player1mana='$usermana', Player1min='$usermindmg', Player1max='$usermaxdmg' WHERE User=".$_SESSION['Username']."")); 

} else {

$selectuser = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username=".$_SESSION['Username'].""));
$currently = $selectuser['Quest'];
$userhp = $selectuser['Life'];
$usermana = $selectuser['Mana'];
$usermindmg = $selectuser['mindmg'];
$usermaxdmg = $selectuser['maxdmg'];
$userdice = $selectuser['dice'];

$MonsterID = $_GET['monster'];
$selectMonster = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE monsterID='$MonsterID'")); 
$monstername = $selectMonster['monstername'];
$monsterlevel = $selectMonster['monsterlevel'];
$monsterdice = $selectMonster['monsterdice'];
$monsterhp = $selectMonster['monsterhp'];
$monstermana = $selectMonster['monstermana'];
$monsterarmor = $selectMonster['monsterarmor'];
$monstermindmg = $selectMonster['monstermindmg'];
$monstermaxdmg = $selectMonster['monstermaxdmg'];

$savefight = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("INSERT INTO fights SET User=".$_SESSION['Username'].", Player1hp='$userhp', Player1mana='$usermana', Player1min='$usermindmg', Player1max='$usermaxdmg', monstername='$monstername', monsterlevel='$monsterlevel', monsterdice='$monsterdice', monsterhp='$monsterhp', monstermana='$monstermana', monsterarmor='$monsterarmor', monstermindmg='$monstermindmg', monstermaxdmg='$monstermaxdmg'"));

}

?> 


<div id="fightcontent">

<div id="fight1">

Health: <?php echo $userhp; ?> <br>
Mana: <?php echo $selectuser['Mana'];?><br>
Damage: <?php echo $selectuser['mindmg']; echo "-"; echo $selectuser['maxdmg'];?>
<br>
<br>
Dice: <?php echo $userdice; ?>
<br>
Quick Slots (3)

  </div>
  <div id="fight2">

Health: <?php echo $monsterhp; ?>
<br>
<?php
if($monstermana == "1") {
echo "Mana: $monstermana";
} else {}
?>
<?php
if($monsterarmor == "0") {
} else { echo "Armor: $monsterarmor"; }
?>
Damage: <?php echo $monstermindmg; echo "-"; echo $monstermaxdmg;?>
<br>
<br>
Dice: <?php echo $monsterdice; ?>
<br>
Spells / Quickslots

  </div>
  <div id="dice">

<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
$selectuser = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username=".$_SESSION['Username'].""));
$userdice = $selectuser['dice'];
$usermindmg = $selectuser['mindmg'];
$usermaxdmg = $selectuser['maxdmg'];


$MonsterID = $_GET['monster'];
$selectMonster = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE monsterID='$MonsterID'")); 
$monsterdice = $selectMonster['monsterdice'];


?>

<?php
if($userdice == 1){ 
$player1roll1 = rand(1,6); 
$player1roll2 = 0; 
$player1roll3 = 0; 
}elseif($userdice == 2){
$player1roll1 = rand(1,6);
$player1roll2 = rand(1,6);
$player1roll3 = 0; 
}elseif($userdice == 3){
$player1roll1 = rand(1,6); 
$player1roll2 = rand(1,6); 
$player1roll3 = rand(1,6); 
}
?>


<?php

if($monsterdice == 1){ 
$player2roll1 = rand(1,6); 
$player2roll2 = 0; 
$player2roll3 = 0; 
} elseif($monsterdice == 2){
$player2roll1 = rand(1,6);
$player2roll2 = rand(1,6);
$player2roll3 = 0; 
}elseif($monsterdice == 3){
$player2roll1 = rand(1,6); 
$player2roll2 = rand(1,6); 
$player2roll3 = rand(1,6); 
}
?>

<?php


$player1sum = $player1roll1 + $player1roll2 + $player1roll3;
$player2sum = $player2roll1 + $player2roll2 + $player2roll3;

if($player1sum > $player2sum) {
$playerdmg = rand($usermindmg,$usermaxdmg);
$monsterhpnew = $monsterhp - $playerdmg;
$fightMonster2 = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("UPDATE fights SET Player1hp='$userhp', Player1mana='$usermana', Player1min='$usermindmg', Player1max='$usermaxdmg', monsterdice='$monsterdice', monsterhp='$monsterhpnew', monstermana='$monstermana', monsterarmor='$monsterarmor' WHERE User=".$_SESSION['Username']."")); 

echo "You hit ";
echo $monstername ;
echo ", with" ;
echo $playerdmg ;
echo "damage. remaining health:";
echo $monsterhpnew;
echo "<br>";

if($monsterhpnew < 1){
$updatefight = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Fight=0 WHERE Username='$user'")); 
$deletefight = @mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("DELETE FROM fights WHERE User='$user'")); 
header("Location: quest.php?action=victory&ID=$currently");
echo "You killed him..."; 
}


}elseif($player2sum > $player1sum) {
echo "Player 2 won";
echo $player1sum ;
echo $player2sum ;
}else{
echo "Draw";
}
echo '<img src="images/dice/'.$player1roll1.'.gif" />'; //echo the image for roll 1 of player 1
echo '<img src="images/dice/'.$player1roll2.'.gif" />'; //echo the image for roll 2 of player 1
echo '<img src="images/dice/'.$player1roll3.'.gif" />'; //echo the image for roll 2 of player 1
echo " VS. ";
echo '<img src="images/dice/'.$player2roll1.'.gif" />'; //echo the image for roll 1 of player 2
echo '<img src="images/dice/'.$player2roll2.'.gif" />'; //echo the image for roll 2 of player 2

}else{
?>


<?php } ?> 

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Roll dice" />
</form>

<?php } ?>


</div></div>
```

Comment: 1. Stop suppressing errors using `@`. 2. Stop using `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated. 3. Use binded parameters and preparded statements.

Comment: Are you sure that you have called `session_start()` before working with $_SESSION array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use the $_SESSION variable you must call `session_start();`

Call this before any of your session code. Though I would possibly recommend reading a little more in to OO PHP and some frameworks.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

This may be a good start for you to help your future programming career.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see `session_start()`
call this at the very beginning of your file if you want to have access to the $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also put quotes around the value you're trying to pass or collect in you SQL queries: `Username='".$_SESSION."'"` ALSO all the above mentioned comments. :)

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. It's pointless to add quotes around something that's a string already, and you don't seem to understand how the $_SESSION variable works.

Comment: Thanks for getting my script to work again :) 
YES, I forgot to start the session!

And how cool is to come back with the new problem, to see it was allready answered! :D ( Username='".$_SESSION."'" )

Thanks a lot.. and you havent probably seen the last of me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [start the session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to use session variables. Just place `session_start()` in the first lines of your script.

Avoid using mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

You don't need to concatenate `"string" . $var . "string"`, you can use `"string {$var} string"` instead, or even better, [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Using PDO it goes like

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1 = ?, row2 = ?");
$query->execute(array($var1, $var2));
```

This avoids [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and makes your code cleaner.